# How to subset all integers and/or numeric values in a character vector?

Tags: r, regex, indexing, subset

Given a vector of strings, for example:

```
set.seed(1)
chr_vec <- c(sample(1:100000, 10), "12to145", "15:19", sample(1:100000, 10), "111.333", "567.1")
```

How can I subset all the strings that are integers? For example:

```
int_vec <- chr_vec[c(1:10, 13:22)]
```

How can I subset all the strings that are numeric? For example:

```
num_vec <- chr_vec[c(1:10, 13:24)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove digits and match with empty spaces (integers) or empty spaces and dots (numerics), i.e.

```
ints <- chr_vec[gsub('\\d+', '', chr_vec) == '']
numerics <- chr_vec[gsub('\\d+', '', chr_vec) %in% c('', '.')]
```

**TESTING**

```
identical(numerics, num_vec)
#[1] TRUE
identical(ints, int_vec)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep` with the pattern.

For integers

```
grep("^\\d+$", chr_vec, value = TRUE)

#[1] "26551" "37213" "57285" "90819" "20168" "89835" "94462" 
#    "66076" "62907" "6179"  "20598" "17656" "68701" "38410" 
#    "76982" "49768" "71758" "99184" "38001" "77738"
```

and for numeric

```
grep("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$", chr_vec, value = TRUE)

#[1] "26551" "37213" "57285" "90819" "20168" "89835" "94462"   
#    "66076" "62907" "6179" "20598" "17656" "68701"  "38410"   
#    "76982" "49768" "71758" "99184" "38001" "77738" "111.333" "567.1"
```